# Bind FlipView with ObservableCollection<writeablebitmap>

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps, flipview

I am developing a windows store application and need help in binding a flipView with an `ObservableCollection<WriteableBitmap>`

Below is the way i am doing it right now ,

**XAML :**

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,20,0" ItemsSource="{Binding BitMapCollection}" Visibility="{Binding FlipViewVisibility}" >
</FlipView>
```

**ViewModel :**

```
ObservableCollection<WriteableBitmap> _bitMapCollection = new ObservableCollection<WriteableBitmap>();

public ObservableCollection<WriteableBitmap> BitMapCollection
{
    get { return _bitMapCollection; }
    set { _bitMapCollection = value; }
}

WriteableBitmap photoWriteableBitMap = await new WriteableBitmap(1, 1).FromContent(new Uri("ms-appx:///Curtain1.jpg"));
WriteableBitmap frameWriteableBitMap = await new WriteableBitmap(1, 1).FromContent(new Uri("ms-appx:///Window1.jpg"));

BitMapCollection.Add(photoWriteableBitMap);
BitMapCollection.Add(frameWriteableBitMap);
```

The images in the flipview are blank. Nothing shows up. Is there any way `ObservableCollection<WriteableBitmap>` can be bound to the XAML directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it with `WriteableBitmap`, but below should work with standard `Image` class (e.g. set the Image's `Source` to that of `photoWriteableBitMap` and bind to a collection of `Image`)

Essentially, you'd need to define a DataTemplate like so:

```
    <FlipView x:Name="flipView"                   
          ItemsSource="{Binding BitMapCollection}" 
          Visibility="{Binding FlipViewVisibility}"             
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Width="200" Height="200" Source="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>    
    </FlipView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could bind to an observable Collection of bitmap Images. Please refer to my implementation of this here [FlipView: HowTo bind a Collection<string> as ItemsSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450252/flipview-howto-bind-a-collectionstring-as-itemssource/37368765#37368765)